# error occur when summing to ints from keyboard in linux assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, sum

an error occur when i try to sum tow ints entered by keyboard in linux assembly

when i execute i get this

> $ ./ss
>
> first int
>
> second int
>
> the sum is :
>
> 6
>
> second int
>
> the sum is :
>
> 6
>
> 5
>
> k

here is the code
nasm -f elf untitled.asm
ld -o ss untitled.o

```
; program to sum to ints from keyboard

    ; macro ro read data from stdin
    %macro read 2
    mov eax,3
    mov ebx,2
    mov ecx,%1
    mov edx,%2
    int 0x80
    %endmacro

    ; macro to write data to stdout
    %macro write 2
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,%1
    mov edx,%2
    int 0x80
    %endmacro

    ; macro to exit
    %macro exit 0
    mov eax,1
    int 0x80
    %endmacro





section .data
    s1 db "first int",0xa
    s2 db "second int",0xa
    s3 db "the sum is :",0xa
    l1 equ $-s1
    l2 equ $-s2
    l3 equ $-s3

section .bss
    a resb 4
    b resb 4
    c resb 6
section .text
    global _start
_start:
    write s1,l1
    read a,4
    write s2,l1
    read b,4

    mov ebx,[a]
    mov ecx,[b]
    call sum
    mov [c],eax
    write c,6
    exit

sum:
    mov eax,ebx
    add eax,ecx
    ret
```

Comment: You need to convert to number first, then add, then convert back. You are trying to add characters, that won't work. PS: your `l1`-`l3` need to be after the respective strings.

Comment: `>>> ord('6')`
`54`
`>>> ord('5')`
`53`
`>>> chr(54 + 53)`
`'k'`
Looks legit.